# Write custom backend logic for visualizing superset graphs

Tags: apache-superset

Is there a provision to write custom logics on my data coming from HIVE database and then visualizing the output in superset. My application demands writing some logics with libraries like numby/scipy and then doing some calculations. I am very new to superset.

Thanks